# Improve the way that I draw the SubItems in a Listview to assimilate the appearance of Windows

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, listview, user-controls

I would like to improve my drawing to write those `...` characters that the default windows Listview draws at the end of each subitem string when resizing the column like you can see in this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J8LghvmLB4E

This is the code that I'm using to draw the subitems:

```
    Dim bounds As Rectangle = e.Bounds
    bounds.X += 5
    bounds.Width -= 5

    Select Case e.Header.TextAlign

        Case HorizontalAlignment.Left

            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.SubItem.Text, e.SubItem.Font,
                                  bounds, e.SubItem.ForeColor,
                                  TextFormatFlags.Left)

        Case HorizontalAlignment.Center

            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.SubItem.Text, e.SubItem.Font,
                                  bounds, e.SubItem.ForeColor,
                                  TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding Or TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter)

        Case HorizontalAlignment.Right
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.SubItem.Text, e.SubItem.Font,
                                  bounds, e.SubItem.ForeColor,
                                  TextFormatFlags.Right)

    End Select
```

Comment: I love to see the enourmous amount of time you're wasting trying to reinvent the wheel just because you didn't pay attention to my advice of using WPF (which already has all these features built-in)

Comment: what exactly is the problem with them?  how is the default Windows method ghastly inadequate?

Comment: @HighCore well thanks for the irony?, but I don't know XAML. And which is the feature name of this, in WPF?

Comment: @Plutonix The default listbox writes some points "..." when resizing the column... my own listview don't do it because I don't know how to reproduce that technique.

Comment: @elektrostudios it is not an irony, I'm being 100% serious. I've been telling you to use WPF since you started this project, and now you're stuck with a bunch of horrible non-portable non-customizable non-scalable winforms hacks. And if you don't know something, like XAML, you can perfectly learn it. It's not impossible, and it's way better than any winforms procedural code behind hack.

Comment: BTW, this feature is called [`TextBlock.TextTrimming`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming(v=vs.110).aspx) in WPF.

Comment: @HighCore I know that use WPF is the best suggestion for a Winform programmer, but it's not easy all the things changes, need to learn new things, saved winforms code snippets need to be translated to work properly in wpf, need to learn XAML, need to translate entire winforms projects from zero, need to keep in mind that separate the data from the controls, but I know it's a good suggestion what you said me, maybe one of those days I give up my head on WPF, sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `TextRenderer` might be the wrong approach for this.  If you use `DrawString` one of the overloads includes a `StringFormat` argument:

```
Graphics.DrawString(String, System.Drawing.Font, Drawing.Brush,
              Drawing.RectangleF, Drawing.StringFormat)
```

You can create a `StringFormat` to control how text is rendered and one of the options is `StringTrimming` which in turn allows you to specify `ellipsis` ( the '...').  These are:

```
    StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
    StringTrimming.EllipsisPath
    StringTrimming.EllipsisWord
    StringTrimming.Word         ' just chops at a word
```

Play with them to see which one you like best.

I have not used TextRenderer much, but one its overloads includes `TextFormatFlags` which allows some ellipsis (`EndEllipsis`).  I dont know how it formats differently than the `StringFormat` method but it doesnt seem as extensive - probably a chop.

Comment: `TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis` did the job!, I don't use `DrawString` because the drawn strings produces an annoying popping effect when resizing, it's really better to use `TextRenderer` at least for this